# Min-Max Normalization in Python

Tags: python, normalization, som

I have been working with Self-Organizing Maps (SOM) on a real world data set (.csv file).I am trying to normalize the data based on Min-Max Normalization to improve the effectiveness.

But I got stuck with an error.The error is like: `"unsupported operand type(s) for list and float"`.

I couldn't find a better solution and I am totally lost with this.

```
for i in range(num):
   trr=eval(str(arr[i]))[0:-31]
print trr
for i in range(num):

   normalized = (trr-min(trr))/(max(trr)-min(trr))
print normalized
```

and declared `trr` at the beginning as:

```
trr = [[0 for x in range(num)] for x in range(num)]
```

Comment: Well, the error itself implies that you're trying to do maths with a list and a float, instead of 2 floats.

Comment: Thank you. As the error occurs in the the statement --->
   normalized = (trr-min(trr))/(max(trr)-min(trr)).I just printed the type of min(trr) and max(trr) and got types as 'list' for both.But what happens is ,I am getting the error "unsupported operand type(s) for list and list" this time even though both are of the type 'list'..

Answer (score 2):

The indentation seems broken, and I'm not sure how to fix it, but, anyway, the key line is:

```
normalized = (trr-min(trr))/(max(trr)-min(trr))
```

Clearly, `trr` here is a list (or you wouldn't be looking for its `min` and `max`) yet you're trying to do arithmetic on it -- no good.  I'd recommend:

```
base = min(trr)
range = max(trr) - base
normalized = [(x-base)/range for x in trr]
```

as being most likely to achieve what I'm guessing you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you.. I have tried but the problem still exists.This time error is like--->"unsupported operand type(s) for list and list" in the line ----> range = max(trr) - base.

Comment: What's the value of `trr` when you `print` it?  Also `print type(base), base` right after computing it and let us know.  I thought (guesses, since you don't **tell** us:-) that `trr` is a list of numbers, but maybe it's a list of lists or something even more fiendish -- **show** us the types & values rather than forcing us to guess!